# Wireless is slow on Ubuntu, fine on Windows dual boot?

Tags: wireless, networking, dual-boot, google-chrome

I know there's been a lot of questions about this, but most seem to have been while using Wubi, or were router and or chipset specific.

For me, internet on my ubuntu partition is slow to start, using latest chrome on 13.04. (i've got an Acer Aspire 5349)
Each page just sits there for 5 or so seconds, then starts to load, and even then takes ages.
However, over on Windows 8, it works flawlessly.  Only had this router for about a month, all the other devices and phones in the house work fine, but just my Ubuntu side of my lappy doesn't seem to work correctly, either with firefox (disastrous), or chrome.

It's not constant though.  Occasionally, it'll load perfectly fine, no problem at all. But about half - 70% of the time, it's just slow to start and slow to finish.

I don't really care that much if it's only a dual boot problem, since i'm about to become Ubuntu-Only in the morning, but if it's gonna be a problem for me then, too, with just ubuntu, then i'd like to see what's going on with it.

On chrome however I've noticed in the little "status bar" in the bottom corner, when it's being slow(before a page even starts loading) it says "Sending Request...", if that helps...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

5s delay to load may indicated DNS problem: unresponsive DNS server listed as the first `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

You may test nameservers response using the command below:
    dig www.ubuntu.com @dns_server_ip_address

Comment: "dig: couldn't get address for 'dns_server_ip_address': failure"  

this is what i get from that... as of now it's not so much the 5s loading now it's only 1 or 2, but pages just take FOREVER to load, especially intense pages like Tumblr where there's lots of GIFs and large hi-res photos covering the page, or youtube and hulu where there's video.  more simple pagees like askubuntu work usually, but sometimes i can't get anything at all to load.

Comment: actually, it's slow as all hell on the windows side now, too.  i guess i'll give it a couple of days, i know my neighbors have had a problem or two also..